# Get the integers from a list, created with BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner in Python and i need some help about this code :

```
from urllib.request import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

req = Request("https://adrianchifu.com/teachings/AMSE/MAG1/project/Xlrda/dsuR/2/J9ED27Y.html")
a = urlopen(req).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(a,'html.parser')
nombres=[]
tout = (soup.find_all('td'))
str_tout=str(tout)     
tout = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', str_tout)]
nombres.append(tout)
print(nombres)
```

From a website, i need to get all the numeric values contained in it (it's juste a part contained in the whole code). I have succeeded in extracting the floats, but i can't get the integers. I have tried many things but i didn't figure out how to do.
Thanks for your help.

EDIT :
For this link (https://adrianchifu.com/teachings/AMSE/MAG1/project/Xlrda/dsuR/2/9GYIGO.html), the method given just below isn't working because in the list, there are integers, floats but also characters. And some chain of characters start with a number, which is complicating the thing. How can i catch the integers but not the characters starting with a number?

Comment: Try `\d+(\.\d+)?` instead of just `\d+\.\d+`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test4.py", line 11, in <module>
    tout = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'\d+(\.\d+)?', str_tout)]
  File "test4.py", line 11, in <listcomp>
    tout = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'\d+(\.\d+)?', str_tout)]
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Python is returning me this, it must be because i also have to deal with characters in my html file.

Comment: I tried running the regexp in JS directly on your webpage and I can confirm that the regexp `\d+(\.\d+)?` is correct: `document.body.textContent.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g).map(parseFloat)`. However I would advice querying only in the table (quick and dirty JS snippet) `document.querySelector("table").textContent.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g).map(parseFloat)`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 This question is about Python, how is JS code going to help OP? Anyway, you'd have to use a non-capturing group as my answer suggests, otherwise `float()` will get empty strings for integers

Comment: @DeepSpace The problem is with OP's regexp that is not matching the integers. Whether the regexp is used in Python or JS does not matter. My comment is to simply point out that `\d+\.\d+` will not match integers while `\d+(\.\d+)?` will. This is also why I wrote it as a comment instead of an answer. Especially when trying to parse a webpage, it is convenient to test out your regexps directly in JS so you can play with the data and explore the actual DOM structure.

Answer (score 0):

Integers don't have the form `\d+\.\d+`, so let's make the decimal point and digits optional with `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$` (note the non-capturing group. It is important).

Then, I'd try to match each `td.text` by itself:

```
req = Request("https://adrianchifu.com/teachings/AMSE/MAG1/project/Xlrda/dsuR/2/J9ED27Y.html")
a = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(a,'html.parser')
nombres = []
tds = soup.find_all('td')
for td in tds:
    if re.match(r'^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$', td.text):
        nombres.append(float(td.text))
print(nombres)
```

This outputs

```
[89.169, 54.893, 19.212, 87.045, 2.248, 99.947, 6190.0, 83.096]
```

As a last improvement I'd use a list comprehenssion with a compiled regex to improve the performance a bit:

```
req = Request("https://adrianchifu.com/teachings/AMSE/MAG1/project/Xlrda/dsuR/2/J9ED27Y.html")
a = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(a,'html.parser')
tds = soup.find_all('td')
numbers_regex = re.compile(r'^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$')
nombres = [float(td.text) for td in tds if numbers_regex.match(td.text)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Yet, what i sent you is a a test for one of the links, and i have a lot of links to treat. For this one https://adrianchifu.com/teachings/AMSE/MAG1/project/Xlrda/dsuR/2/9GYIGO.html       The code is not working. I guess it's because one of the character chain is starting with a number. How do i have to modify the code you sent to me to get over this?

Comment: This isthe error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test4.py", line 13, in <module>
    nombres.append(float(td.text))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3ID1386'

Comment: @Shikantaza I've updated the regex you should use (`^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`)

Answer (score 0):

You should keep doing with you own way, and you can complete your job by using `split`.

```
from urllib.request import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

req = Request("https://adrianchifu.com/teachings/AMSE/MAG1/project/Xlrda/dsuR/2/J9ED27Y.html")
a = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(a,'html.parser')
nombres = []
tout = [ele.text for ele in soup.find_all('td')]
tout = [text if not re.findall(r"^\d+\.\d+",text) else int(text.split(".")[0]) for text in tout]
print(tout)
# [89, 54, 19, 'OIK3XF02PS', 87, 2, 99, '6190', 83, 'E2RYAFAE']
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking for regex for matching the integers.

^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$

All positive non-zero integers between 1 and 999. You can adjust the upper range of this expression by changing the second number (ie 2) in the {0,2} part of the expression.

Courtsy: http://regexlib.com